# Adobe Illustrator guidance needed

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I'm having a hard time creating this shape. Could anyone guide me as to what shapes I could use to create the shapes within the circle.

[image: shape]

Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to **GDSE** - please take a look around [tour] to get a sense of who and what we are as a community. Consider referring to [ask] and [answer] a question to understand how best to frame queries (you did pretty well, BTW) and what to expect of answers (WELZ crushed it, as always) and then please also look over [help/behavior] to learn about our community's behavioural expectations - may help you see what WELZ means around stats. Thanks for a good, solid question with clear effort shown!

Answer (score 6):

I started with creating 3 circles, with diameters 99, 66 and 33.

Use the *Ellipse Tool* (<kbd>L</kbd>) and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Click in the center to create the next shapes aligned. Then in the popup you fill out the size.

[image: 3 circled]

Now I added a line across the center and **Right Click → Transform → Move** > 16.5 pt (vertical) and selected copy (did this twice)

[image: lines 1]

Now did the same thing with a vertical line transformed horizontally.

[image: lines 2]

Now using the *Shapebuilder Tool* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) merge the shapes together, and hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> to remove the edges at the end.

[image: shape builder gif]

Now add some color:

[image: colored]

Comment: Wonderful, thank you so much for such a comprehensive answer WELZ. I SO appreciate it. :)

Comment: @MarkUsman my pleasure! If you would please consider accepting an answer, especially if the answer solved your problem, it'd be very helpful. Accepting answers helps other visitors and is great for the site's stats.